# Bluetooth not working - Any ideas?

Tags: bmw, bluetooth

I have a 2008 BMW 328xi.  I'm told all BMW's from 2002 on have Bluetooth.  I looked online and found a video from a dealership that showed a person pressing and holding the telephone icon on the steering wheel to activate the radio to search for a Bluetooth device to connect with.  I did this for quite some time (in excess of a minute I'd estimate) but the radio never indicated it was trying to pair with a Bluetooth device.

Is it possible there is a short somewhere, or a fuse that's burned out, or some other "quick hit" I can perform before I bring this to a shop and spend money to get it fixed?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey there.  I'm citizen on the other sites.  We have encountered one another.  Let me know if the info below is helpful and correct.  If not, I'll get the right stuff for you.  Welcome to the Mechanics site on SO!  Cheers.

Comment: Turns out my particular car did *not* have bluetooth, had to go to a dealership for them to tell me.  Oh well...

Answer (score 3):

**There's a procedure to pair your phone**

Here is a [video from BMW](http://www.bmwusa.com/Standard/Content/Owner/OwnersManualVideos.aspx?sort=2&namodelcode=0838&videoguid=9aeda1e8-a3f0-4619-8b21-adc9b8db0ee5) for your vehicle.

Here is the [owners manual for your vehicle](http://cache.bmwusa.com/PDF_97112459-9e53-458e-a82b-24dfa04a2a9e.arox?v=8c4d1799-deca-401e-bcf5-927b076af96e).

The procedure involves going to the main menu on your audio device and selecting phone.  The procedure is pretty straightforward from there and detailed in the owners manual starting with pairing your phone on page 187.

The PDF is protected so I couldn't copy/paste the list of directions, too much to retype.  I'm sure you have the idea.  Goto page 187 and you should be good to go!

/btw - welcome to the site!